# error with partial_fit in MultinomialNB classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the code below, the data is a list of sentences and the "y" column (data.metagroup) is a list of classes - a straightforward classification problem.

**Problem:**

I want to use `partial_fit` with the MultinomialNB classifier.

Based on the docs, I'm passing in a sparse vector for `X` (called `xtrain`), a simple series for `y` (called `ytrain`), and an `np.array` for `classes` which is a list of all possible classes.

The goal is to eventually use a subset of `xtrain` and `ytrain`, but I have to get it working first.

The relevant docs can be found here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes 
(42633,3809) (800,3809) (42633,3809)
```

Would appreciate any insights.

```
 def make_xy(data): 
     vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (1,3), min_df = 3, stop_words='english')
     X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data.sentences)
     y = data.metagroup 
     return X, y, vectorizer

 x, y, vv = make_xy(data)

 xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.30)

 clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=1)
 clf.partial_fit(xtrain, ytrain, classes=np.array(y), sample_weight=None)

 predictions = clf.predict(xtest)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-cc08c1d170fd> in <module>()
     48 clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=1)
---> 50 clf.partial_fit(xtrain, ytrain, classes=np.array(y), sample_weight=None)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.pyc in partial_fit(self, X, y, classes, sample_weight)
        530         # Count raw events from data before updating the class log prior
        531         # and feature log probas
    --> 532         self._count(X, Y)
        533 
        534         # XXX: OPTIM: we could introduce a public finalization method to

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.pyc in _count(self, X, Y)
        689         if np.any((X.data if issparse(X) else X) < 0):
        690             raise ValueError("Input X must be non-negative")
    --> 691         self.feature_count_ += safe_sparse_dot(Y.T, X)
        692         self.class_count_ += Y.sum(axis=0)
        693 

    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

Comment: add full code and data

Comment: Honestly, it's just a list of sentences with numerical classes in the "metagroup" column - a two column pandas dataframe.  There's nothing else in the code but pulling the data from csv, etc.  This is everything relevant.  Thanks.

Comment: the only way to reproduce the error is to have the data. if you cannot shar ethe data add some artificial data that lead to the same error

Comment: Understood.  I've put sample data
 at: https://github.com/philopaszoon/capstone1/blob/master/dd_sample.csv and it can be read with the following line:  data = pd.read_csv('dd_sample.csv', sep='\t', quoting=3, encoding="utf-8")

Comment: @paszoon, why do use `partial_fit` for such a tiny data set?

Comment: This is only a subset of the actual dataset, which is much larger.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of error.

Comment: I have added that ..

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.  The problem turned out to be that I was passing in the literal Y column from my data, when what it really wanted was the list of unique values indicating possible classification.  Thanks to anyone who looked at this.